# Create a custom annotation for JPA @Entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Whether it is possible to create a custom JPA @Entity in spring boot application.

In my application I need to switch between relation database and Mongo DB with single entity class creation without any duplication of entity class.

I thought of creation my own annotation let say @MyOwn, so that I can inject the annotation based on database need.

@MyOwn will be act as @Entity as well @Document annotation based on database selected.

I am able to custom the @Document entity with @MyOwn annotation.

But for @Entity I am not able to do it.

I am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.mt.mtamp.employee.entity.Employee
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:583) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:233) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
... 49 common frames omitted
```

Let say

```
@Entity 
public class Employee {

 @Id
 public Long id;

 private String employeeId;

 private String employeeNAme;

 private String firstname;

 private String lastName;

}
```

Here in this above class I need to replace @Entity with my own annotation let say @MyOwn

The behavior of the @MyOwn should as same as @Entity annotation.

The class should be look like below after my own annotation

```
@MyOwn 
public class Employee {

 @Id
 public Long id;

 private String employeeId;

 private String employeeNAme;

 private String firstname;

 private String lastName;
```

}

Own Annotation class:

[image]

Comment: That's not possible. Hibernate only looks for classes with Entity annotation

Comment: Could you just have both annotation set on the same class ?

Comment: @PierreDemeestere Can you please elaborate your comments

Comment: Can't you have `@Entity` and `@Document` on the same class  ? In the same way you could have JPA and Json annotations on the same class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have custom annotation for `@Entity`, because `@Entity` annotation can be added only to class (target = TYPE), and needs identifier in annotated class (`@Id` or `@EmbeddedId`).

That means that when you add `@Entity` annotation to your custom one annotation, you must provide `@Id` or `@EmbeddedId` annotated field... but you can't because you try create annotation.

On the other hands, hibernate searches only classes with `@jakarta.persistence.Enttiy` or `@javax.persistence.Enttiy` (depends on hibernate version) so will not find classes annotated with your custom annotation.